# I want list items to be hidden based on string input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, django, frontend

So I have these list items in the div below:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Dissapearing Game</h2>
    <div>

        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item">Door#1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item">Door#2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item">Door#3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item">Door#4</li>
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item">Door#5</li>

    </div>
```

My Goal is to make them dissapear upon typing the string "None" into it.  The JavaScript goes as so:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

        var TextInsideLi0 = document.querySelectorAll('li')[0].innerHTML; // Retrieving text line 1

        var TextInsideLi1 = document.querySelectorAll('li')[1].innerHTML; // Retrieving text line 2

        var TextInsideLi2 = document.querySelectorAll('li')[2].innerHTML; // Retrieving text line 3

        var TextInsideLi3 = document.querySelectorAll('li')[3].innerHTML; // Retrieving text line 4

        var TextInsideLi4 = document.querySelectorAll('li')[4].innerHTML; // Retrieving text line 5


        var MenuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.go'); // Retrieves the Menu Item by Class 'go'


        //BELOW executes the CSS to hide the list item when "None" string is entered:

        if (TextInsideLi0 == "None") {
                MenuItems[0].classList.add('hidden')            
            } else if (TextInsideLi1 == "None") {
                MenuItems[1].classList.add('hidden')
            } else if (TextInsideLi2 == "None") {
                MenuItems[2].classList.add('hidden')
            } else if (TextInsideLi3 == "None") {
                MenuItems[3].classList.add('hidden')
            } else if (TextInsideLi4 == "None") {
                MenuItems[4].classList.add('hidden')
            }

    </script>
```

ABOVE works for the 5 list items..  I just want clues in adding a for loop for it which will allow me to enter infinite list items with the same functionality.

Comment: Solved. You can check .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot give each item the same id.

```
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item1">Door#1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item2">Door#2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item3">Door#3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item4">Door#4</li>
        <li class="list-group-item go" id="item5">Door#5</li>
```

you can do the whole thing with these.  Using the loop on the li elements on the page, you control each of them innerHTML and give them a class.

```
   const allElements = document.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item");

     allElements.forEach(element => {
        if(element.innerHTML == "None") {
          element.classList.add("hidden");
        }
     });
```

Comment: Thank you that SO works.  Golden.  Now on to continue my JavaScript studies.  This is where the learning happens.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As CanUver mentioned, it's not allowed to use the same ID for more than one html element. Besides that, your problem doesnt need any ids for every menu entry. As you already said, you can get your menu element, so all you need to do is loop through the inner elements of you menu, check for the inner html and attach your desired css class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the children of container or any parent element and loop through them
`document.querySelector('.container').children`
Visit here for reference https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ehy there!

You can use this snippet to do what you've described:

```
document
  // select all `li.go` items
  .querySelectorAll("li.go")
  // set `hidden` attribute to `true` when the specified text has been found
  .forEach((item) => (item.innerText === "None" ? (item.hidden = true) : null));
```

Here what i've used:

- [forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [innerText property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)
- [hidden attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden)

Bye !

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm going to try this one too!

Comment: Happy to be helpful !